# Parse not sending push with promises

Tags: node.js, parse-platform, promise, angular-promise

I'm trying to send push notifications with promises. Cause first I'm fetching data from server after I'm getting args. this is my code.

```
var fromUser = request.object.get('fromUser').fetch().then(function(user) {
  var userName = user.get('username');
  userCredits.userName = user.get('username');
  //userPromise.resolve(userName);
  userPromise.resolve(userName);
});
promises = [userPromise, groupPromise];
Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(function(result1)  {
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.containedIn('channels', members);
  console.log("push sending #######");
  Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
      aps: {
        alert: {
          "loc-key": type,
          "loc-args": [userCredits.userName, userCredits.groupName]
        },
        isJSONPush: 'true',
        badge: 'increment',
        'sound': 'default',
        type: type,
        group: group,
        message: message,
        messages: messages,
        activity: request.object,
        "mutable-content": 1
      },
    }
  }, {
    useMasterKey: true
  }, {
    success: function() {
      console.log('##### PUSH OK');
    },
    error: function(error) {
      console.log('##### PUSH ERROR' + error.message);
    }
  });
  //return response.success(result1);
}, function(error) {
  console.log("error + " + error);
  return response.error(error);
});
```

So if I use it outside of promises scope it is working. But when I'm trying to use it in promises scope it's not working.

And also this is output which I'm getting error.

parse-server-push-adapter APNS cannot find vaild connection for

Answer (score 0):

could use more of your code to see what's going on here.  i.e. could use the declaration of `userPromise` and also `groupPromise`

But I'm pretty confident that your promise is not working the way you think it is.

Here's my re-write of the bit that you gave us making an assumption or two about what I think the full code looks like.  Note how I take the result of the `request.object.get('fromUser').fetch()` and put that right into Parse.Promise.when

```
var userPromise = request.object.get('fromUser').fetch();
var groupPromise = groupQueryThatReturnsAPromise;


// Note that if you put the promises not in an array
// but sep with commas, you know what's returned.... 
Parse.Promise.when(userPromise, groupPromise).then(function (user, group) {
  // just to make sure we got here with what we want :)
  console.log(user, group);
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
  query.containedIn('channels', members);
  console.log('push sending #######');
  return Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data: {
      aps: {
        alert: {
          'loc-key': type,
          'loc-args': [user.get('username'), group.get('groupName')]
        },
        isJSONPush: 'true',
        badge: 'increment',
        sound: 'default',
        type,  // just some fancy object notation if the key and value are the same :).
        group,
        message,
        messages,
        activity: request.object,
        'mutable-content': 1,
      },
    },
  }, {
    useMasterKey: true,
  });
}).then(() => response.success) // fancy new style "fat arrow" function declaration
.then(null, e => response.error(e)); // chain an extra then in case we error out in the when...
```

PS: sorry I can't run the code to validate it before putting it here, hope this helps, but the prob is def the promise so if you concentrate on making sure each part of the promise chain is working the way you think it is with debug statements, you'll get it straight which will help you going forward for sure!  Good luck.

Comment: No it didn't work actually. I'm still looking why its not working on my code.

Comment: Hello guys, could you please give me a feedback ?